# Using the OR (|) function in regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

So I am using a Regular Expressions to extract all areas from a document. The problem is the areas are sometimes expressed with m2 and sometimes with m². I thought I can solve this problem by using the OR (|) operator like this

```
(\d+.\d+|\d+.\d+?\s)m(2|²)
```

but when I use this regex with the findall function he returns this for example:

```
('7,96 m2', '7,96 ', '2')
```

The desired output is of course:

```
('7,96 m2')
```

Am I using the brackets wrong?

Comment: Use non-capturing groups or `re.finditer` to get the `match.group()` values. Besides, you can fix your regex, `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\s?m[2²]`

Comment: modifying regex pattern seems to work, try ```re.findall("\d+,\d+\sm\d", "7,96 m2")```